# ORA-000904:"ATTRIBUTE". Invalid identifier 00904.00000-"%s:invalid identifier"

Tags: oracle9i

One of our client is getting error **ORA-000904:"ATTRIBUTE". Invalid identifier 00904.00000-"%s:invalid identifier"** while running script for creating the trigger in Oracle SQL Developer. I searched for this in the forums......i got this happens when using 1.5.4 version of oracle with the oracle9i. If they use 1.5.3 or lower version of Oracle SQL developer then this can be resolved.

But they tried 1.5.3 also but they are still facing the issue. They are also telling that this is happening due to the **SHOW ERROR** command after the Trigger Definition.

Can anybody have the idea about this???please help me...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the trigger is referring to an identifier called `ATTRIBUTE` that does not exist in the current scope.  If you post the code, we can be more specific, but I would guess that the trigger is incorrectly expecting a table to have a column named `ATTRIBUTE` or that the code is trying to use a local variable `ATTRIBUTE` that has not been declared.

Comment: initially i also assumed this...but this is not the case..
I am pasting piece of the script that is throwing this error "ORA-000904:"ATTRIBUTE". Invalid identifier 00904.00000-"%s:invalid identifier"



CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER OHM_ADMIN.ABSEMLTP_BEFOREDELETE_MEMO
 BEFORE DELETE ON OHM_ADMIN.ABSEMLTP
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF :OLD.FLDBODY <> 0 THEN
  DELETE FROM OHM_ADMIN.ABSEMLTP_MEMO WHERE FLDTYPE = :OLD.FLDBODY AND FLDPARENTRN = :OLD.FLDREC_NUM;
  END IF;
END;
/
SHOW ERRORS


Do you see any problem with this???
Thanks Justin For your previous response..

Comment: @sunilkumar - Please edit your question to include the code so that the code can be formatted.  And post the full output of the `SHOW ERRORS` command including the line number.

Comment: I don't have the exact error log because they sent me the screen shot of the error...In the screen shot, there is one prompt window that is telling about the error as follows:

An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

ORA-00904:"ATTRIBUTE" invalid identifier
00904:00000-"%s:invalid identifier"
*Cause:
*Action:
Vendor code 904